# In Flex, AdvancedDataGridColumn.itemToLabel() returns nothing when the item is a Boolean value?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm parsing an AdvancedDataGrid, and the dataField for one of the columns is a Boolean value.  The column also has an itemRenderer (that I cannot change or modify).  itemToLabel seems to work on every other column except for the one in question (the boolean).  Ideally I would get a '0' or '1' or 'true' or 'false' string returned.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all items visible? If so I'm wondering if you could use the itemRenderer to access data for a specific row, and thus the field that you care about. Something like this, maybe?

```
private function getBooleanValueForItem(item:Object):Boolean
{
     var ir:IListItemRenderer = myGrid.itemToItemRenderer(item) as IListItemRenderer;
     return ir.data.dataField;
}
```

where dataField is the dataField for the boolean column? You can only get itemRenderer for visible rows, thus my initial question.

Comment: This ultimately led me in the right direction.  The field in question had a custom item renderer which was manipulating the real data (in the datafield) and using a boolean value to display (or not display) an icon in the datagrid.  I created a toString method to spit out "True" or "False" as an alternative to the on/off icon.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could set the labelFunction for the DataGridColumn.

```
function booleanLabelFunction(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
{
  return item ? "True" : "False";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no control over the advanceddatagrid.  My parsing method takes a advanceddatagrid as a parameter, and I cannot guarantee that a labelfunction will be applied.

Comment: Could you check to see if the data is a boolean then treat is specially?

Comment: Do you know how I can check to see if the data is boolean for a given AdvancedDataGridColumn

Comment: Since you are using the itemToLabel function i am assuming you a reference to the data. You could use the dataField property of the AdvancedDataGridColumn and then do a type check. Something like `if (data[dataGridColumn.dataField] is Boolean)`.